# Почему перед responsive ставится пробел?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Понятно, ноги растут от W3Schools... Не учите JS по их кодам. Там устаревший, или даже по старым меркам - плохой код. http://learn.javascript.ru/ — один из хороших ресурсов.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME В видеоуроке(там без bootstrap был этот код) нашла, хотя недавно в W3Schools тоже нашла тот же код, и оттуда копи-пейстнула сюда. Я JS изучаю из learn.javascript.ru и по видеоурокам. Просто не могу найти нормальный материал для изучения создания адаптивного сайта(HTML+CSS). Почти все видеоуроки по HTML+CSS для beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `className` — строка, содержащая названия классов элемента, в таком виде, как они записаны в HTML... в котором несколько разных классов должны быть разделены через пробел.

А `x.className += " responsive";` то же самое, что и

`x.className = x.className + " responsive";`

Если не поставить пробел - окажется, что у него там один длинный класс, а не два разных:

```js
let moo = document.querySelector('.moo');

console.log( 'className: ' + moo.className );
console.log( 'Type: ' + typeof moo.className );

moo.className += "класс-без-пробела";

console.log( 'className: ' + moo.className );
```

```html
<div class="moo boo doo zoo foo CLASS-111"></div>
```

Это еще добавление класса... а с удалением заморочек еще сильнее. Поэтому в современном JS добавление/удаление классов прописывают через classList, который хранит список классов, а не строку, и имеет встроенные методы:

```js
let demo = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');

demo[0].classList.add('red');
demo[1].classList.remove('red');

demo[2].onclick = function(){
  demo[2].classList.toggle('red');
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">Не было красного цвета - а появилось...</p>

<p class="demo red">Был красный цвет - да пропал.</p>

<p class="demo red">А мой цвет будет переключаться при клике.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Запись

```
<div class="class1 class2"/>
```

обозначает, что `div` имеет два класса `class1` и `class2`.

Соответственно ваш код

> ```
> if (x.className === "topnav") {
>   x.className += " responsive";
> } else {
>   x.className = "topnav";
> }
> ```

делает следующее

1. если у элемента присутствует **только** класс `topnav`, то **добавить** ему еще и класс `responsive`
2. Иначе установить ему только класс `topnav`

Пример в коде

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.responsive {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">Click</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Здесь класс `topnav` отвечает за наличие рамки вокруг элемента, а класс `responsive` за наличие желтого цвета фона. Их комбинация `topnav responsive` дают элемент желтого цвета с черной рамкой